# UIButton added into content view of UITableViewCell only appears when cell is selected

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm having problems trying to add buttons into a UITableViewCell's content view.
The button cannot be seen. But, when I click on the cell and when it is selected (with the default bluebackground), the button can be seen.

The table view controller is created with: `initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UIButton *theButton;


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    theButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(800, 25, 32, 32)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:theButton];
    theButton.tag = 1;
    [theButton release];

}

if(indexPath.section ==0){
        //...logic...
    }else if(indexPath.section ==1){
        //...logic...
    }else{
        cell.textLabel.text = @"some string";

   theButton = (UIButton*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];
    [theButton setImage:theImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the table view cell's text label background color clear with `[UIColor clearColor]`.